# Disable Clamav / Amavis / SA in Postfix on Debian

Tags: debian, anti-virus, postfix, spamassassin, clamav

I would like to disable Clamav / Amavis / SpamAssasin in Postfix on Debian Squeeze 6.0.8 as I have I outsourced my AV to other server.

I tried commenting content_filter and receive_override_options in /etc/postfix/main.cf (saved and restarted server) but I still see clamav and amavis process when I run top.

Comment: Are you sure you failed? Could it be that clamav and amavis came on top of ~top` because they were monitoring the rest of your system, not postfix?

Comment: Good point, any way how could I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Amavis, or amavisd, is the component that relays e.mail messages to the antivirus. Since it does nothing else, and you wish to get rid of this function, you should simply un-install it.